# Каким образом с помощью Python распарсить иерархию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список вот такого типа, в котором иерархия задана открывающим и закрывающим символом (s - открывающий, e - закрывающий):

```
[ ["s", "n1"], ["s", "n2"], ["s", "n3"], ["e", "n3"], ["e", "n2"], ["s", "n4"], ["e", "n4"], ["e", "n1"]
```

Необходимо распарсить его так, чтобы для каждого n_ получить имя его родителя.
По идее так же делается например и в парсинге XML, но чего то до меня пока не доходит как это сделать. Спасибо за помощь заранее.

Comment: "s - открывающий, e - открывающий" Наверное, предполагалось, что один из них закрывающий?

Comment: Да, сори, перепутал(

Comment: Откуда парсеру взять имя родителя? Из данной структуры можно извлечь информацию только о глубине вложенности элемента.

Comment: Имя родителя - это n1, n2...nn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать преобразовать этот список в JSON и потом создать из него уже словарик с помощью библиотеки json. Пример такого кода:

```
import json

s = [ ["s", "n1"], ["s", "n2"], ["s", "n3"], ["e", "n3"], ["e", "n2"], ["s", "n4"], ["e", "n4"], ["e", "n1"] ]

result = "{"

for item in s:
    if item[0] == "s":
        result += ("\"%s\": {" % item[1])
    if item[0] == "e":
        result += "},"

result += "}"
result = result.replace(",}", "}")

d = json.loads(result)
print(d)
print(d["n1"])
print(d["n1"]["n2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Действия:

- Создаем список родителей и по мере нахождения `s` добавляем в последнего родителя новый элемент, а сам элемент становится последним родителем.
- Когда встречаем `e`, удаляем последнего родителя из списка.

Попробуйте:

```
items = [["s", "n1"], ["s", "n2"], ["s", "n3"], ["e", "n3"],
         ["e", "n2"], ["s", "n4"], ["e", "n4"], ["e", "n1"]]

data = dict()
parents = [data]

for status, name in items:
    if status == 's':
        parent = dict()
        parents[-1][name] = parent
        parents.append(parent)
    else:
        parents.pop()

print(data)  # {'n1': {'n2': {'n3': {}}, 'n4': {}}}
```

Результат:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
# {
#     "n1": {
#         "n2": {
#             "n3": {}
#         },
#         "n4": {}
#     }
# }
```